# Magento2 url issue

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls, redirect-url, url-key

My magento2 website in following url to be show

> catalog/product/view/id/9583

but i need like

> powder-9583.html

so what step we required to achieve this.

and also search engine is on on backend.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you input the URL-Key for the product https://prnt.sc/n45mar. So if you need to URL rewrite, please follow the steps Marketing->SEO&Search->URL Rewrites->Add URL Rewrite. In the landing page specify the inputs accordingly https://prnt.sc/n45lgx. You can use the Rewrite Type for this rewrite.

Comment: Have you imported products or what ?

Comment: yes i am import product